# Why use the 'AccountInfo' account type?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

I'm looking for clarification on when and why I should use the 'AccountInfo' type instead of passing an account as an instruction parameter in anchor_lang.

For example:

Both following programs do the same thing.
Both have been tested to work.

**Using instruction parameter:**

```
#[program]
mod hello_friend {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, friend_address: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.friend_address = friend_address;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    friend_address: Pubkey,
}
```

**Using AccountInfo:**

```
#[program]
mod hello_friend {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.friend_address = ctx.accounts.friend_address.key();
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    /// CHECK: Your friend's wallet address
    pub friend_address: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    friend_address: Pubkey,
}
```

Is there a reason why I would use one method over the other?
Which one is best practice?

Comment: You're right. Edited, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ZombieGhost! You may also wish to change the accepted answer - the existing answer is good but John's is much more comprehensive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between an 'account' and a 'public key'. In the given example, you are just saving the public key of friend_address account in your new_account so it can be achieved by simply passing the public key as an argument.

But if you want to read from or write to an account, you have to pass the account in the instruction. Suppose in the above case, instead of public key if you wanted to read the data field of friend_address account, you can't do that by simply passing the public key of the account as argument, but had to pass the account in the instruction.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you! This was on my mind for a while. This was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

**You shouldn't use `AccountInfo`**. Using `AccountInfo` performs no additional checks on the account provided to the instruction, and [`AccountInfo` may be going away in future](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2794).

#### Checking accounts

It's usually preferable to validate an account using [one of the supported Account types](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/index.html), which is one of the benefits of using Anchor.

If you use the `Account` wrapper like this:

```
pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>
```

Then Anchor will automatically try to validate the account (`new_account`) provided to the instruction and deserialize the account data (as `NewAccount` type).

```
pub struct AccountInfo<'a> {
    pub key: &'a Pubkey,
    pub is_signer: bool,
    pub is_writable: bool,
    pub lamports: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut u64>>,
    pub data: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>,    // <---- deserializes account data
    pub owner: &'a Pubkey,    // <---- checks owner program
    pub executable: bool,
    pub rent_epoch: u64,
}
```

You can also [use the `anchor_spl` crate for working with the token program in Anchor](https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/).

#### If you really do not need to check the account

Anchor provides an `UncheckedAccount` type which is the equivalent of using `AccountInfo`, but explicitly indicates to other developers that the account is unchecked, and makes you state why you believe it should not be checked:

```
/// CHECK: insert a good reason why this account is not being checked
pub new_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to understand why the AccountInfo and UncheckedAccount types are actually needed though. Why even use the account type if you don't want anchor to perform checks? Why not just pass it as a function parameter?

Comment: Any accounts used in the instruction would need to be included in the account validation struct. When to use the `UncheckedAccount` type would be dependent on the program, which you can use `///Check:` to leave a comment for why the account is unchecked. You might see something like  `/// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account`

Comment: If you are passing accounts to another instruction via CPI, you might accept them in your program as `UncheckedAccount` or `AccountInfo`, since the other program will perform those Anchor checks anyways.

Comment: I tweaked this a little to emphasize what to do, put the links to the different Account types earlier and show the `/// CHECK` bits. Hope that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading through this a while later and realising that something wasn't expressed clearly enough in the question and answers.

You should avoid using AccountInfo, UncheckedAccount, and passing in pubkeys in instruction parameters when possible.

It's very important to check that the account being provided is an account of the type you're expecting.

Otherwise a malicious user could pass in a different account, causing a vulnerability in your program or at least causing your program perform unexpectedly.